# Why free() function in C++ only deallocating 8 bytes of memory?

Tags: memory-management, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get different results when I dereference a pointer after freeing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078677/why-do-i-get-different-results-when-i-dereference-a-pointer-after-freeing-it)

Tried it in case of characters as well, what it did that after 8 values the 9th value was correct while first 8 were showing garbage value, as it is case here, first two values are showing garbage while the third is as it is. And thus only first 8 bytes are getting deallocated. Why is it so? you can also increase the number of indexes in array to check.
someone please explain HOW FREE() METHOD IS WORKING HERE?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
int *arr;
arr=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);
arr[0]=10;
arr[1]=20;
arr[2]=30;

free(arr);
for(register int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: you need to understand how the (m)alloc/free functions work - in a nutshell, deallocation doesn't mean that the values aren't accessible, it means that the memory has been freed for future allocations.  So, until some arbitrary time, the variable(s) may or may not be available.

Comment: @kevin: but y the first 8 bytes are not accessible??

Comment: @kevin : i need an answer to where those 8 bytes are used cause i know that all the rest values will be there but why not first 8 values?

Comment: the value of any variable after free is undefined - add code before and/or after your current source and you will get different results. just rest assured that, after free, those variables aren't usable any more.

Comment: i know they are not usable any more..
but after first 8 bytes the values are not undefined.
they are as they were..
in case of char as well
tell me about first 8 bytes... can you enlighten me where those 8 bytes are getting used and that only first 8 bytes are showing garbage values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`free()` basically only tells the runtime system "I'm done with this memory, feel free to reuse it for other things at your convenience." In other words, reading the memory after `free()` is entirely unsupported and may give any value whatsoever, including anything in the range from reading back exactly what you wrote to crashing your program.

Comment: it is not giving random values... exactly the same values after 8 bytes
i just want exact answer of why the first 8 bytes are lost.. while rest values are still there... answer of WHY 8 ONLY?

Comment: @user1985038 The 8 bytes are entirely implementation dependent, and reading the data is not specified behaviour, so the allocator is free to do anything. In this case, you see some bytes being unchanged, but changing to for example Valgrind's allocator, you may see totally random data in your entire free'd block. If you really need the answer for a specific allocator, you'll most likely have to go to the source code of the specific malloc library version you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the value of arr after you have freed it.  That is invalid and any results are not defined.   In this case, I'm guessing your implementation of free is using the first 8 bytes for some record keeping (such as a free list pointer or buddy length).

Answer (score 0):

The call to free() informs the memory allocator that the memory can be reused in a future allocation.  It does not somehow magically invalidate the pointer you previously received.  That pointer still points... somewhere.  Depending on what else is happening in the system, your original values may still be at the memory location pointed to.

If

> arr=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*3);

set `arr` to say `0xabcdabcd` (which represents an address in memory), `arr` is still set to that exact value after your call to `free`.  Something is still at that address.  That something may or may not be the values you put there.