# C malloc and free functions's strange behaviour

Tags: c, string, memory, malloc, free

```
char str1[]= "To be or not to be";
char str3[]= "To eat or to eat";
char * str2=(char*)malloc(80);
//char str3[40];
str2[0]=NULL;
/* copy to sized buffer (overflow safe): */
strcat(str2, str1);
strcat(str2, str1);
free(str2);str2[0]=NULL;//<<==Marked line
strcat(str2, str3);
strcat(str2, str3);
```

In the following code , the operation works fine where it prints "to eat or not to eat" 2 times but if i removed "str2[0]=NULL;" from the marked line it doesn't work and prints "to be or not to be"twice and also "to eat or not to eat twice" why is that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get different results when I dereference a pointer after freeing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078677/why-do-i-get-different-results-when-i-dereference-a-pointer-after-freeing-it)

Answer (score 1):

That's undefined behavior

```
free(str2);
```

releases memory pointed to by the pointer to the heap and makes the pointer invalid. Since that using that pointer and accessing that memory can yield any results.

Having said that, it looks like in your implementation the memory is still accessible and so subsequent `strcat()` calls just append new strings to the original two strings. So you had `To be or not to be` twice in the buffer and you have `To eat or to eat` appended twice and so you see the result you described in your question. You should not rely on this behavior - in other conditions you can have whatever other results, including but not limited to memory corruption, program termination, anything else.

Answer (score 1):

That is not strange behavior. Free completely removes the reference from memory. You are essentially deleting the variable with that `free(str2);` Better would be to use `bzero(str2,80);` from the header string.h

Answer (score 0):

Better than this is to simply use strcpy and strcat like the following :

```
char str1[]= "To be or not to be";
char str3[]= "To eat or to eat";
char * str2=(char*)malloc(80);
//char str3[40];
/* copy to sized buffer (overflow safe): */
strcpy(str2, str1);
strcat(str2, str1);

strcpy(str2, str3);
strcat(str2, str3);
```

That will do it the safest and easiest way :)