# Issue regarding memory allocation in C

Tags: c, malloc, free

For some reason, I cannot manage to correctly free the structure I created, which goes as follows:

```
struct dictionary{

char word[50]; // Word to be described
char definition[150]; // Definition of said word
struct dictionary* next; // Linked list structure

}*dic;
typedef struct dictionary Dic;

Dic* newWord(char word[], char definition[]){
    Dic* dc;
    dc = malloc(sizeof(*dic));

    strcpy(dc->word,word);
    strcpy(dc->definition,definition);
    dc->next = NULL;

return dc;
}
```

Now, if I do something like:

```
dc = newWord("Word","definition");
free(dc);
printWord(dc);
```

where:

```
void printWord(Dic* dic){
    if(dic){
    printf("<%s>\n",dic->word);
    printf(".%s\n",dic->definition);
    }
}
```

will result in no word being printed, yet the definition still being printed, which I can only assume means I'm not properly freeing this structure's memory. How do I go by properly doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get different results when I dereference a pointer after freeing it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078677/why-do-i-get-different-results-when-i-dereference-a-pointer-after-freeing-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a pointer after freeing it. This is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a), which means the C compiler can do whatever it wants. It can crash, it can appear to behave properly, or it can do anything in between. Calling `free` on a pointer doesn't set it to `NULL`, it releases your claim on the memory, but you have to set it to `NULL` yourself.