# use malloc to set an array of strings then clear it

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

I want to make an array of string using malloc, and then clear ALL the allocated memory, I believe that I use malloc correct but I can't understand what I'm doing wrong when I try to clear it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void print_arr(char* arr[]);
void clear_arr(char* arr[], int size);
int main()
{
    int number = 10;
    char **myarr = malloc((number+1)*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++)
    {
        myarr[i]=NULL;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        char str[] = "word";
        int len = strlen(str);
        myarr[i]=malloc((len+1)*sizeof(char));
        strcpy(myarr[i], str);
    }
    print_arr(myarr);
    clear_arr(myarr, number);
    print_arr(myarr);
    free(myarr);

   return 0; 
}
void print_arr(char* arr[])
{
    for (int i = 0; arr[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",arr[i]);
    }

}
void clear_arr(char* arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        free(arr[i]);
    }

}
```

but my output for number = 3 is:

```
word
word
word
Pi╛
word
word
```

it's look like that only the first "cell" of the array is getting free and the other doesn't effected. what wrong with my clear_arr function?
I'm using VScode to compile if that matters...

Answer (score 1):

That's because you try to print something that you free'd. The `free` function deallocate the memory but you still have the address in the array.

What you can do is:

```c
void clear_arr(char* arr[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        free(arr[i]);
        arr[i] = NULL;
    }

}
```

This way, the print function won't loop through an array of free'd pointers.

There is a better way to malloc and copy a string, you can use the function `strdup`.

Your code could be optimized this way:

```c
int number = 10;
char **myarr = malloc((number+1)*sizeof(char*));
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
{
  myarr[i] = strdup("word");
}

myarr[number] = NULL;
```

Comment: I know I'm trying to print something that I've freed, but I want to know why only the first entry looks like it's freed: print gibberish and the rest of the entries print the string.

Comment: When you try to access a free'd memory, the behavior is undefined. Maybe your data will still be there, maybe another program use this memory and write other data in it, anything can happen since it's not your memory.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078677/why-do-i-get-different-results-when-i-dereference-a-pointer-after-freeing-it